# Reddit style comment chains in React

Tags: react.js, jsx

This isn't meant to be a fully-featured anything, isn't meant to involve any sort of api interactions. It's just meant to be a proof-of-concept of how I could implement nested reddit-style comments.

Every comment is either a top level comment or a reply to another comment. Each level of nesting is indented and is color coded. The color-coding wraps back in on itself (eg if there are 5 defined files, then the 6th layer of nesting should have the same color code as the 1st layer of nesting).

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments : [
                {
                    'user': 'user1',
                    'text': 'text1',
                    comments: [{
                        'user': 'user3',
                        'text': 'responding to text1',
                        comments: [
                            {
                                'user': 'user1',
                                'text': 'responding to user3'
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    'user': 'user2',
                    'text': 'text2'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            {
                this.state.comments.map(comment => (
                    <Comment comment={comment}/>
                ))
            }
        </div>;
    }
}

class Comment extends React.Component {
    renderSidebar(level) {
        const colors = ['green','orange','red'];
        const index = level % colors.length;
        return {'border-left':'solid 3px ' + colors[index]};
    }

    render() {
        const comment = this.props.comment;
        const subComments = comment.comments || [];
        const level = this.props.level || 0;
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <div className="main-comment" style={this.renderSidebar(level)}>
                    <p className="user" style={{'margin-bottom':'0','opacity':'0.3'}}>{comment.user}</p>
                    <p className="text">{comment.text}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="subcomments" style={{'padding-left':'2em'}}>
                    {subComments.map(comment => (
                        <Comment comment={comment} level={level + 1}/>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/z318wsq6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Test` class

1. In the scope of code you provided, the `div` is useless and may be omitted:

```
render() {
  return this.state.comments.map((comment, index) => (
    <Comment key={index} comment={comment}/>
  ))
}
```

2. However, as React warns you in the console, don't forget to [pass a `key` prop to your array items](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) (added in the snippet above).

## `Comment` class

1. The method name `renderSidebar` suggest to me that it will return something that React can render, but it returns an object of CSS styles instead. For that reason, I'd rename it to `getSidebarStyle`.
2. Since the method `renderSidebar` doesn't depend on anything except its parameters and doesn't alter any instance variables (it's a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)), you can move it outside the class.
3. The array of `colors` has nothing to do with the logic of selecting a color depending on the intendation level. Depending on your coding style preferences, you could move it to outside the method and capitalize it.
4. When rendering the subcomments, set a `key` prop on your array items as above.
5. [JSX is camel-cased](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) and that's why React warns you in the console to change your CSS property names (e.g. `border-left` to `borderLeft`), also allowing you to omit the quotes.

Generally, your code is in good shape & all of the comments above are more or less only improvements. To help you move faster, I suggest always checking the console for helpful warnings and using tools such as [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) and a linter for your JS dialect to help you while programming.